# Video poster gets stretched in chrome when playing a non-loaded video

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, video

I'm facing situation where a video set up with `object-fit: cover` gets its poster stretched when trying to play the video. The poster gets stretched to a 2:1 aspect ratio that I noticed is the default ratio of the default `video` tag if no styles are applied.

I'm not able to reproduce in other browsers and it doesn't seem to be related to a CSS setting.

Minimum code to reproduce looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Video Error Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            video {
                width: 300px;
                height: 600px;
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <video poster="https://via.placeholder.com/300x600" muted>
            <source src="not-important" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </body>
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.body.querySelector("video").play();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</html>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6c7yjg8a/

any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a check on the readyState of the video element like so:

```js
if (video.readyState < 1) {
    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", video.play)
    video.load()
} else {
    video.play()
}
```

so the `play` command is only triggered if the metadata is loaded, if not it waits.
Apparently with the metadata the sizing gets done correctly

https://jsfiddle.net/9qjLtyho/